# Ansible, set default password for ansible_user

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory with various host, some are using `ansible_user=root` and specific password, and other host use my current human login, thus I don't set `ansible_user` or `ansible_password`, `ansible_sudo_pass`

Inventory

```
[glpi]
nginx-eu ansible_host=8.8.8.8
elk-emea ansible_host=8.8.8.8 ansible_user=root ansible_password=foo ansible_sudo_pass=bar
```

- When I run the ansible as below for `elk-emea`, I don't have to set `--user`, `--ask-pass`, `--ask-become-pass`, as it is set in the host config

  ```
  ansible-playbook toto.yml -i Inventory --limit elk-emea
  ```
- When I run the ansible as below, for `nginx-eu`, I have to provide login, and password. I usually have them in a file `~/.ansible/passwords.yml`

  ```
  ansible-playbook toto.yml -i Inventory --limit nginx-eu --extra-vars @~/.ansible/passwords.yml
  ```

Then I'd to run the playbook for both hosts

```
ansible-playbook toto.yml -i Inventory
```

**Issue** :

- it works for `elk-emea`, but not for `nginx-eu` as there is no password for this host.
- If I use `--extra-vars`, due to [variable precedence in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) it won't work for `elk-emea`, the config variable for this host will be ignored, setting in done using extra vars will be used :(.

I'd like to have a very low way to set the credentials, but I don't find the way to proceed.

Thanks for reading.

**What do you think about this solution ?**

In the file ~/.ansible/passwords.yml, define variables using your login (replace the `mylogin` with your `$USER` value)

```
mylogin_password
mylogin_sudo_pass
```

And in inventory, use the `USER` env var to build a variable and get its value. With this solution, users of ansible only have to provide those specific variables.

```
nginx-eu ansible_host=8.8.8.8 ansible_password="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'USER') + '_password'] }}" ansible_sudo_pass="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'USER') + '_sudo_pass'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ansible host_vars for that, when needing to set different variables for different hosts this is the easiest way.
You can read about it [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-vars) but essentially you can create a different file for each host with the variables you need for it (in your case the user ans password, and the playbook will use the variables according to the host you have created the vars for.

The hierarchy of the files should look like that:

```
- playbook.yml
- host_vars /
  - firstHost.yml
  - secondHost.yml
```

And the files content:

```
ansible_user: user
ansible_password: password
```

If you prefer the password to be encrypted, you can use [ansible-vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault.html) for that.

Comment: I do also, I use the host_vars to store vaulted password when this is dedicated to host.
My problem is that it is not used when I use --extra-vars due to other host where I need to connect with my own login account instead of a local for exemple root login

Comment: So can't you set them in host_vars as well?

Comment: I do for hosts where a specific is used, like root. But for other hosts, the login to use is my own, $USER, which is not the same for all users using the ansible scripts.
In that later case, using a hard coded login is not possible, and if I use extra vars, login are overwritten for hosts where specific users is needed ...